# Curly brackets usage without condition

Tags: javascript

I noticed in some legacy Javascript code, the usage of curly brackets without condition. Does anyone know what it means?

```
var myList = myFile.variables;
for (j = 0; j < myList.length; j++) {
    var i = myList[j].name;
    {
        if (i == "test") {
            myList[j].value = "a";
        }
        if (i == "demo") {
            myList[j].value = "b";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make code lines into a block. meaning nothing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block